# Disconnect sessions and maps

Tags: powershell

I would like my script upon being cancelled (Ctrl + C, or otherwise) to disconnect any sessions or mapped drives that may still be open.

We have a large customer base and I can't have powershell sessions open on the target server.

Does anyone have any ideas about how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Try` ... `Catch` ... `Finally` block](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315350.aspx) to run your cleanup code:

```
try {
  # Your code
} catch {
  Write-Error "Something went wrong: $($_.Exception.Message)"
  # Additional error handling here
} finally {
  # Cleanup Code
}
```

It's important to note that if you put any output in your finally block it won't show if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> as this keyboard shortcut stops the pipeline:

> Note that pressing CTRL+C stops the pipeline. Objects that are sent to the pipeline will not be displayed as output. Therefore, if you include a statement to be displayed, such as "Finally block has run", it will not be displayed after you press CTRL+C, even if the Finally block ran.